# Jquery validation Input

Tags: jquery, validation, input

```
 $('#err input').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      $(this).data('errors', "ABC " + $(this).data('err') + " " + $(this).val());
   });

 $('#go').click(function(){
   var code = "";
   $("#err input").each(function(){
    code += $(this).data('errors') + "\n" || '';
   });
   $('#x').html(code);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="err">
   <input data-err="A" id="e-1" type="text"/>
   <input data-err="B" id="e-2" type="text"/>
   <input data-err="C" id="e-3" type="text"/>
</div>
```

How to make validation, if Input will be empty, then this Input not will be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#go').click(function(){
   var code = "";
   $("#err input").each(function(){
     //This condition will check for empty values
     if($(this).val()){
        code += $(this).data('errors') + "\n" || '';
     }

   });
   $('#x').html(code);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning false from a submit handler cancels the default form submit function. So use:

```
$('#go').submit(function(){
   //do validation here
   if(validationFails)return false;
 });
```